# onBackPressed with fragments and saving fragment state

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to save fragment state so I use fragment .add() and fragment .show() methods.
the part I use to add fragments in my mainActivity is

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_content, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

On back pressed in the fragment and getting back to it the get fragment by tag returns null

```
       if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    hideTransactions(CURRENT_TAG);
                    fragmentTransaction.show(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG)).commit();
                }
            };
```

although onBackPressed the state of the fragment is right(TAG_PREV returns not null) in the on back pressed method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }
    if (CURRENT_TAG == TAG_HOME) {
        return;
    }
    navItemIndex = 0;
    TAG_PREV = CURRENT_TAG;
    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
    loadHomeFragment();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: you want to save fragment state ? or any other thing you want?

Comment: I want to save the whole fragment so when I find it I don't use fragment.add() again I use fragment.show()

Comment: Why don't you want to add the fragment? Do you have a reason for this?

Comment: I'm calling a web-service and don't want to make the service call again just show the previous results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addToBackStack` saves the transaction, in this case: `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_content, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);` and when you press back(`onBackPressed`) you are reversing that transaction.  So that will imply you are removing the previously added fragment.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know this before.
Is there any way to save the transaction on using backbutton ?

Comment: try hiding the fragment after adding and before commiting. and when you are back you need to call show on that fragment you hid.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to maintain entire fragment in back stack, There is no provision given by android teams.

You have to use onSaveInstanceState for saving current state/data when you are leaving fragment.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, " onSaveInstanceState.");
    savedInstanceState.putString("greeting", "Hello");
}
```

After that when again coming on that fragment you have to use.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String greeting = (savedInstanceState != null) ? savedInstanceState.getString("greeting") : "null";
    Log.i(TAG, " onCreate: " + greeting);
}
```

Please let me if it dosen't work for you.

Comment: onSaveInstanceState is not recommended as it is not reliable.

Comment: But I'm using navigation drawer and save the whole fragment states using transaction.hide() and . show()